# Why can't the HttpResponse be changed after 'next' call?

Tags: c#, asp.net, middleware

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) {
    app.Map("/hahaha", HandleMapTest);
    app.Run(async (context) => {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
    });
}

public static void HandleMapTest(IApplicationBuilder app) {
    app.Use(async (context, next) => {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Before!");
        await next.Invoke();
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("After!");
    });
}
```

The resulted response only has "Before!After!", but missing the "Hello World!". Why does it happen?

The [Asp.net docs](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/middleware.html#creating-a-middleware-pipeline-with-iapplicationbuilder) said:

> Avoid modifying HttpResponse after invoking next, one of the next components in the pipeline may have written to the response, **causing it to be sent to the client**.

Which I don't understand what the "cause it to be sent to the client" mean.

Answer (score 1):

By invokeing next you are passing control on to the next middleware in the chain which means that the current middleware loses control and further middlewares may have written to the response, flushed it or even closed the stream.

"Cause it to be sent to the client" means that one of the further middlewares may have done something, like the options above, to cause the response to be sent from your server to whatever client that is invokeing it. This is not guaranted to have happend, as proven by your code, but it is possible. Therefore, it is discuraged to write to the httpresponse after invoking next just in case.

Comment: But in my case, it is the content written in the "next" call that was ignored, not the changed made after that (namely the "After!"), which should not be caused by either the next call writing to the response or closing the stream.

Comment: Actually... you are right. My problem is caused by something else. I found out that the `Run` will not be inserted to the pipeline if the `Map` matches the request.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the reason is the `app.Run` will not be inserted to the pipeline if the `app.Map` matches the request. This is quite unexpected to me.