# Response pipeline

Tags: asp.net-core, response, middleware, pipeline

I came across a difficulty while was working with Asp.net core 1.0 RTM. For example in case bellow we will see output result as "-Message_1--Message_5-":

```
 public class MessageMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly IApplicationBuilder _app;

    public MessageMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        _next = next;
        _app = app;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var started1 = context.Response.HasStarted;//false
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("-Message_1-");
        var test = true; // will hit this line
        var started2 = context.Response.HasStarted;//true
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("-Message_5-");

        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

But in this case (header "Content-Type" was added) the result will be only "-Message_1-" and execution is really stopped:

```
  public class MessageMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly IApplicationBuilder _app;

    public MessageMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        _next = next;
        _app = app;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var started1 = context.Response.HasStarted;//false
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("-Message_1-");
        var started2 = context.Response.HasStarted;//true
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
        var test = true; // will NOT hit this line
        var started3 = context.Response.HasStarted;//will NOT hit this line
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("-Message_5-"); //will NOT hit this line

        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

I found only this remark in official documentation:

> Avoid modifying HttpResponse after invoking next, one of the next components in the pipeline may have written to the response, causing it to be sent to the client.

and this question at SO: [Why can't the HttpResponse be changed after 'next' call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38006951/why-cant-the-httpresponse-be-changed-after-next-call)

But it's not enough to understand interaction with props of HttpContext.Response during middleware pipeline and how this interection affects on final result  - headers and body content of HttpResponse.

Could somebody explain general behaviour of processing response by ASP.NET core? For example, when response headers are send to client and how setting HttpContext.Response properties(headers, body content) affects on this? 
When pipeline inside(outside) middliware is terminated?

Thank you!

Comment: Don't set headers after you have written something to the response stream. You can only set headers before the data is sent to the client. Once you send any data to the client you can't change or set the headers anymore, because headers need to be set before the content is sent (they are submitted before the content)

Comment: Tseng, when sending data to client event emitted? What do you mean "send data"? Is sending only headers? Where is watcher and how it works?

Comment: `await context.Response.WriteAsync("-Message_1-");`, depending though on if you have (or don't have) any middleware that does buffering. Even then though, you wouldn't have control on when it gets flushed. And a line after that you do `context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";`which is setting the headers **after** the content has been written

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule, when the client makes a request to the server, it gets back a response.  That response contains headers and a body.  The headers contain many pieces of information about the response like the content type, encoding/compression used, cookies, etc.  Here is an example of the headers sent back by the live.asp.net site as seen in the chrome developer tools:

[image]

The other part of the response is the body.  It often contains html or json.  Here is a screenshot of the body for the same response:

[image]

The easiest way to think about it is to think of these two being sent together to the client, first the headers then the body.  So as a developer, your only opportunity to set any value on the response object that affects the headers is up to the point at which you start sending the body.  One you begin sending the body of the response you can no longer change the headers because they are sent as the first part of the response just before the body begins sending.

That's why @tseng said "Don't set headers after you have written something to the response stream".

If a developer isn't familiar with http headers they might not realize that `context.Response.ContentType = "text/html"` is changing a header, but under the hood, that's exactly what it is doing.  Likewise, setting a cookie changes a response header under the hood.  In general, if you are changing some property of the response object you should ask yourself "will this change an http header?" and if the answer is "yes" then you need to do it before you make a call to `Response.WriteAsync`.

Comment: Roc, thank you for detailed answer. If i understand correctly the response headers and response body may be send separatly: at the begginig headers are send then body. Is it right? If yes, when Asp.net core strarts to sent headers. What is the event it watching? Writing to response stream? And I was surprised than code after setting header not being execute at all.

Comment: Think of it as a stream of data being sent to the client.  At the beginning of that stream is the headers, then after the headers are sent, the next thing sent in the stream is the body.  WriteAsync (or any other call that sends body text to the client) forces the headers to be sent since they precede the body in the stream that is sent.

Comment: Ron, so if in some middleware I start writing to respose stream, ASP.core begins sending respose to client. And in a second middleware I can't replace body stream content if i will not use some buffering middleware?

Comment: That's right, you can't replace what has already been streamed out over the network to the client.

Comment: @malonowa: You'd have to create some *funky* buffering middleware (which is registered early on) in this case, which creates a memory stream and replaces the Response stream with it. Then all other middleware will write into this memory stream, after the `_next(context)` call you could read this memory stream and write it into the real response stream. This however some impact on performance and response time, as more memory will be used and user won't receive any data until all middlewares are finished